# Find the singularity of the polynomial $p(z)=a_0+a_1 z+a_2 z^2+\cdots+ a_n z^n$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $p(z)=a_0+a_1 z+a_2 z^2+\cdots+ a_n z^n$ be a polynomial of degree $n\geq 1$, where $a_0$ and $a_n$ are both non-zero. Then $$f(z)=\frac{1}{p(1/z)}$$, which is meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}- \{0\}$ ,

1. has a removable singularity at $z = 0$ and is non-vanishing there.
2. has a removable singularity at $z = 0$ and has a zero of order $n$ at $z = 0$.
3. has a pole of order $n$ at $z = 0$.
4. has an essential singularity at $z = 0$.

Now I took the simplest polynomial $p(z)=1+z$, then $$f(z)=\frac{z}{z+1}=1-\frac{1}{z+1}=z-z^2+z^3-\cdots$$ hence it has a removable singularity at $z=0$ and it vanishes at $z=0$. So $2$ is correct. Is my solution correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can write $p(1/z)=(1/z)^nq(z)$ where $q(z)$ is a polynomial in $z$ and $q(0)=a_n\not=0$.  Therefore, $\frac{1}{p(1/z)}=z^n\cdot\frac{1}{q(z)}$.  Since $q(0)\not=0$, $\frac{1}{q(z)}$ is analytic near $0$.

Comment: I didn't get the complete picture from your answer. Elaborate a bit please and is my solution correct or something is wrong?

Comment: Where did you get lost?